# How can I start a project on GitLab repo with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, synchronization, gitlab

Good morning.
I just create a GitLab private repo to work in a project with some people. When I add GitLab repo to Eclipse, it says there aren't projects (and it's true). I would know how to create a project and sync with online repo so other members can see my project and codes.

I tried to start a project in git\repoName\ folder, then right-click and choose Team->Commit, but changes wouldn't save (in gitLab repo's website, it says "Repo is empty").
I tried to follow some online guides, but without success.

Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 2):

*Eclipse 4.2 and newer, comes default with (E)Git installed. There is a good [Eclipse git tutorial from Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html)*.

**Create a GitLab git repository**

- Log into GitLab
- Create a project / git repository
- Copy the `https` url from the project, used for cloning

**Adding an GitLab git repository in Eclipse**

- Open the Git perspective in Eclipse
- Use **Clone existing Git repo**, as shown in [Using git repository view](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#repository_view)

Now all the git functionality from Eclipse can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a cloned repository available in Eclipse (eGit) that is empty. If not, follow the steps in the answer from Verhagen.

By now, you have a cloned repository that is marked with "`[NO HEAD]`", indicating that no commit has been made.

1. Start creating a new project by using your project type of choice; I'll use Java project for simplicity: File menu > New > Java project
2. in the New Java Project wizard un-tick the "`Use default Workspace location`" checkbox; instead, choose the directory where you cloned your empty GitLab project, and append the name of the project (this is to make Eclipse create a directory inside the repository, just in case you later want to create more projects in the same repo).
3. Fill in the wizard as you usually do. When you are done with the different steps, you'll have a new project, that is also marked with "`[NO HEAD]`"
4. Create some source files you want to share (e.g. HelloWorld.java)
5. Synchronize workspace (right click on the new project > Team > Synchronize workspace) you will see that now there are files to commit. Pay attention to those files, since some of them ( .gitignore, and maybe .classpath, .project,.settings directory... depending on how you share your projects) you'll want to add to the .gitignore.
6. right click on the files you want to commit, fill in the commit message and click "Commit and Push". Click Next
7. Since it is a new repository, you'll have to configure the Push action. I selected HEAD as source and HEAD as destination. You might want to do the same, at least for this first commit+push; later on, you might choose to add some specs for branches, etc.
8. The Push Confirmation will show you that the new branch `master:master` will be created.
9. Both project and repository lost the "`[NO HEAD]`" marking
10. You can check gitlab site to confirm your files are there.